# How to translate "day after day"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

How to translate "day after day" in the sentence `I am writing my novel day after day`?

As it describes the verb writing, I think an adverb should be a good idea. But how to place the adverb mark on *tago post tago*? It is not even a single word! A single world would be nice. (But I am open to all propositions.)

Answer (score 12):

*Mi skribas tagon post tago.*

It's not an adverb, it's an accusative of time.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this a situation that requires the distributive *po* since the key thing isn't that you keep going "day after day" but that you are doing a bit each day (*)?

*Mi skribas mian romanon potage.*

(*) If this means *Vi NaNoWriMas Esperante* then wow, cool.

Comment: This certainly works, although it's rather unusual. "Tagon post tago" is by far the most common translation, but the word "poiome" is used to mean "little by little", so by analogy it's not wrong to use "potage".

Answer (score 1):

- *Mi skribas mian romanon tago post tago* (Zamenhofa, malnova)
- *Mi skribas mian romanon tagon post tago* (logika, nuntempe plej uzata)
- *Mi skribas mian romanon per tago post tago* (la plej **per**a?)
- *Mi skribas mian romanon tag-post-tage* (la plej *vizaĝ-al-vizaĝe*)

> [PMEG 12.3.9. Forlaso de rolvorteto](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/rolvortetforlaso.html):
>
> *Ni **paŝo post paŝo**, post longa laboro, atingos la celon en gloro. Aŭ ...paŝo**n** post paŝo..., ...**per** paŝo post paŝo...*
>
> [Tekstaro (La Ondo de Esperanto)](http://www.tekstaro.com/):
>
> [...] *ĝi poste akceptos paŝ-post-paŝe la saman liston*

Vidu ankaŭ la jenan iom [rilatan demandon](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5002/o-vorto-post-o-vorto).

Answer (score -1):

Rilate al tio, kio vi estas pridiskutantaj, mi al mi demandas se oni ankaŭ povas uzi la finaĵon -op por signifi la enhavon de iu ajn kvanta objekto pli konkreta k ne sole de nombro abstrakta : ekzemple, tagopo da laboro, aŭ labortagopo povus signifi la kvanto da laboro farita en unu tago (tre malsama ol labortago, kiu estas tago en kiu deviĝas labori), semajnopo da laboro, kvanto da laboro farebla en unu semajno, sammaniere kun sepopo da tagoj aŭ tagsepopo kiu estas plimalpli samafero kun semajno.  Se poviĝos eble diri la nomon tagopo, kial ne la adverbo tagope?

Ne taûgas ankaŭ la nura ripeto tagtage por signifi unu tagon post la alia?  Aŭ tagtagope aŭ tagoptage?

Comment: _-op-_ havas sencon nur post nombrovorto, ĉar ĝi indikas, el kiom da anoj konsistas kolektivo. *_tagopo_ ne havus sencon tiel.

Comment: Tamen, mi komprenus ĝin