# O-vorto + post + O-vorto

Tags: word-usage

En Tekstaro (Robinsono Kruso) mi trovis:

> [...] mi eble estus povinta surterigi la tutan ŝipŝarĝon, pecon post
>   pecon
>
> Estis enuige vagi, tagon post tagon

Mi komprenus ekz. *meti pecon post pecon* kiel *meti unu pecon post alian pecon* (do en la postan aŭ malantaŭan lokon de alia peco), sed ĉi tiu estas malsama senco al tiu de la supraj frazoj, ĉu ne?

Mia demando estas ĉu en la du supraj citaĵoj estas iel pravigebla la uzado de *pecon post peco**n*** kaj *tagon post tago**n***. Ĉu ne estu *pecon post peco* kaj *tagon post tago*?

Parenteze mi aldonu ke en Tekstaro troviĝas sufiĉe da frazoj kun strukturo simila al *tago post tago* kontraste al *tago**n** post tago*. Tio konfuzigis min ĝis mi eltrovis, ke la formo sen N-finaĵo estis pli uzata de Zamenhof, ol tiu kun N-finaĵo. Tion bone klarigas PMEG ĉe [Forlaso de rolvorteto](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/rolvortetforlaso.html):

> Zamenhof tamen normale ne uzis rolmontrilon ĉe la unua O-vorto. Li
>   plej ofte traktis tiajn esprimojn kiel tutaĵojn, opiniante, ke la
>   rolvorteto inter la du O-vortoj sufiĉas por montri la frazrolon de la
>   tuta esprimo.
>
> Nuntempe multaj preferas uzi N-finaĵon aŭ alian rolmontrilon ĉe la
>   unua vorto, kiam la frazrolo tion postulas. Tio estas gramatike pli
>   logika, sed la Zamenhofa dirmaniero restas bona, kaj eĉ sufiĉe
>   eleganta alternativo.

Answer (score 1):

Vidu **post** en la [Reta-Vortaro](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/) (al post, post ...-n  ↝).

Ekzistas uzo de la prepozicio kun direktindika akuzativo: kiam la sekva peco *iras* post la pasinta(n) peco(n).

Answer (score -2):

Mi mem dirus: "pecon post peco" kaj "tagon post tago". Ĝenerale 'post' ne postulas akuzativon.

Laŭ Fundamento de Esperanto (http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko_angla.html) "8. All prepositions govern the nominative case."